# C# System.Diagnostics.Process: can't launch a 32 bit exe file in 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, process, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 32 bit exe file compiled with Turbo Pascal. I need to launch it. It worked well when I had Windows 7 32 bit, but now I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, and I get the following exception:

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

To make sure it works on 32 bit systems, I launched the C# program in a 32 bit platform - it works.

So how can I launch a 32 bit exe file in 64 bit OS?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915398/loading-a-32-bit-process-in-a-64-bit-environment

Comment: I'm confused. Are you launching a Turbo Pascal program or a C# program? Last time I used Turbo Pascal was 15 years ago and it was 16 bit.

Comment: Are you launching the Turbo Pascal program from within C#?

Comment: I'm launching a Pascal program from a C# program. I'm not sure, it could have been compiled with Free Pascal, which supports 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turbo Pascal could only generate 16-bit code, there was never a version that could create 32-bit executables.  Running 16-bit code requires a virtual machine that uses the real-mode emulation support in the CPU ([virtual 8086 mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode)).  This emulation is not available if the processor is running in 64-bit mode.

You cannot run 16-bit processes on a 64-bit operating system.  You may have a shot at getting it going with the [DOSBox emulator](http://www.dosbox.com/).

Comment: But I could launch it on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @Alex - Yes of course, that one isn't running a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I agree with Hans, double check that your progam is not really 16 Bit, Windows 64 dropped support for 16 bit. You can check it with a program like [EXE Explorer](http://www.mitec.cz/exe.html)

Comment: You are right. The pascal program was indeed 16 bit. I recompiled it with Free Pascal (I have the sources), so now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're launching the 32 bit exe from within a .NET (C#) application, then you'll need to set the target for your .NET app to x86. If it's set as Any CPU, then it will run as a 64 bit process on a 64 bit OS and therefore won't be able to launch the 32 bit process.

**Edit:** This MSDN article explains how to modify this setting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b4eyb0k.aspx

**Edit 2:** As Gabe points out, there shouldn't be a reason why the 64 bit app could not start a 32 bit exe. I know you can't use a 32-bit DLL from within a 64-bit app. Just thought it would be worth trying since the documentation doesn't specify if that same restriction exists when using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch an exe.

Comment: Dennis: There's no reason a 64-bit app wouldn't be able to launch a 32-bit app.

Comment: @Gabe I think you're right. Maybe I was thinking of using a 32-bit DLL from within a 64-bit app.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch 32bit application from 64bit application.

C# Example 1:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\MyApp.exe");
var process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

C# Example 2:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\MyApp.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a 64 bit compiler for Turbo Pascal so I think your only choice is to compile your app targeting a 32 bit enviornment.