# Can't start powerpoint from start menu shortcut in c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, windows-7-x64, process.start, shortcut-file

I'm attempting to start a program based on a start menu shortcut. In particular, I'm trying to launch powerpoint based on its start menu shortcut. To accomplish this, I am using the IWshRuntimeLibrary.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string searchTerm = "powerpoint";

    string startMenu = Environment
        .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu);

    string shortcutPath = Directory
        .GetFiles(startMenu, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Length)
        .First(p => p.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));

    WshShell shell = new WshShell();

    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath);

    Console.WriteLine(shortcut.TargetPath); //prints: C:\Windows\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\pptico.exe

    Process.Start(shortcut.TargetPath, shortcut.Arguments);
}
```

I am able to successfully find the shortcut as well as create an IWshShortcut object.  However, once I attempt to run the shortcut's backing application (via Process.Start(shortcut.TargetPath, shortcut.Arguments)), a Win32Exception occurs:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message=The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=193
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName, String arguments)
       at Scratch.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\jhampton\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Scratch\Scratch\Program.cs:line 26
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The only related answer I could find was in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814713/c-system-diagnostics-process-cant-launch-a-32-bit-exe-file-in-64-bit-os/3814841#3814841). My project was already building as an x86 application

Since it seems relevant, here's some background on my system. I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit, and have Microsoft Office 2010 installed. This is part of a console application written in Visual Studio 2010, targeting .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

I'm in the process of investigating the following alternative solutions:

The Windows API Code Pack: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack
Shortcuts without IWshRuntimeLibrary: [How to resolve a .lnk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c/220870#220870)

Sorry about the lack of sensible links.  It's my first post and apparently I can't insert more than one using a tags.

Comment: did you try outputting the contents of `shortcut.TargetPath`?

Comment: @mookid8000: I forgot to include it in the example code, I'll edit it in. In the meantime, here's what I got: "C:\Windows\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\pptico.exe".  I should note that powerpoint is indeed installed, licensed, and functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should simply work:

```
Process.Start(shortcutPath);
```

You don't need to open the lnk, just ask windows to execute it. Behind the scene, Process.Start will do a **ShellExecute** that knows how to process a .lnk.

Comment: This works perfectly. Per usual I made things overly complicated. Thanks.